# Node.jsの環境でwebpackを実行すると、`WARNING`の注意文が表示されました。この注意文に対する対処方法（既存ファイルの修正や注意文の無視など）を教えてください。

Tags: webpack

いつもお世話になっています。
下記の質問についてご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示を願います。

---

### 【質問の主旨】

webpackをインストールすると、`WARNING`の注意文が表示されました。この注意文に対する対処方法（既存ファイルの修正や注意文の無視など）を教えてください。

### 【質問の主旨】

#### 1.

モジュール構成のアプリを1ファイルにまとめるために、インストールしたwebpackを実行しました。実行内容と結果は以下のとおりです。`WARNING in configuration`以下の文章が黄色で表示されています。

```
$ npx webpack
Hash: 9**************a
Version: webpack 4.35.3
Time: 360ms
Built at: 2019-07-11 17:09:51
  Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
main.js  1.05 KiB       0  [emitted]  main
Entrypoint main = main.js
[0] ./src/index.js + 1 modules 385 bytes {0} [built]
    | ./src/index.js 135 bytes [built]
    | ./src/util.js 250 bytes [built]

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/
```

#### 2.

webpackを実行したあとのコードは[GitHub](https://github.com/echizenyayota/js_reciepe_v2_ch11-)にUPしています。

#### 3.

注意文をキーワードとしてGoogle検索をすると、いくつか似たような問題について言及されている記事が見つかります。ただしいずれも`package.json`を修正することが書かれています。一方自分がインストール・実行したwebpackには`package-lock.json`だけで、`package.json`が存在しません。そのためどのファイルに何を記述すれば良いのかよく分かりません。

（参考ページ）
https://qiita.com/MasanoriIwakura/items/32f9be227adab21d7f87

#### 4.

今回の質問は[「JavaScript逆引きレシピ 第2版」](https://www.shoeisha.co.jp/book/detail/9784798157573)のP520の内容に基づいています。本には`WARNING in configuration`のことについて言及されていません。

---

以上、ご確認のほどよろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack の mode については https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/ に記載があります。 mode は環境に合わせた最適化を有効にするオプションで、 `none` （最適化なし）、 `development` （開発環境向け最適化） `production` （本番環境向け最適化；デフォルト）の3種類があります。

mode を指定するには以下のように webpack.config.js に設定を書くか、

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  // 他の設定…
};
```

あるいは `webpack --mode=production` のようにコマンドラインオプションを使います。

Comment: uasiさん。コメントありがとうございます。いただいたコメントに基づいて2つ質問がございます。
1. webpack.config.js のファイルはnode_modules/webpackの直下に保存するのでしょうか？
2. ファイルの保存や記述内容が正しく行われているかどうかどのように確認するのでしょうか？
以下、質問に関する補足です。1. webpack.config.jsはnode_modules/webpackの直下で保存しています。詳細はGitHubにUPしています。 https://github.com/echizenyayota/js_reciepe_v2_ch11-/commit/fa00ebb509df91a2d32edc846cc54b28bedf7758
2. 別解として教えていただいだ`$ webpack --mode=production` を`node_modules`より1つ上のディレクトリで実行すると、`-bash: webpack: command not found`と表示されます。
たびたびの質問で恐れ入りますが、お手すきのときにでも教えていただければ助かります。よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: @echizenya_yota 1. src, node_modules などがあるディレクトリの直下に置いてください。 node_modules は npm や yarn が管理するディレクトリであり、中にユーザーのファイルを置くことはありません。 2. 特に確認する方法はないと思います。 webpack に `--verbose` オプションを渡せば表示されるエラーがより詳細になるかもしれません。 `command not found` と表示されるなら `npx webpack --mode=production` で実行してください。

Comment: uasi さん。たびたびのコメントありがとうございます。`webpack.config.js` を `node_modules` や `src` などと同じ階層に配置し直しました。その上で、`$ npx webpack --verbose` 、 `$ npx webpack` 、 `$ npx webpack --mode=production` のコマンドを実行したところ、`WARNING`などの注意文が表示されることはありませんでした。おかげさまで私が投稿した質問は解決ができたと思います。今後ともどうぞよろしくお願いします。
https://github.com/echizenyayota/js_reciepe_v2_ch11-

Answer (score 1):

はじめまして。
Githubを見たところ、webpack.config.jsがないようです。

Comment: ymdさん。コメントありがとうございます。いただいたコメントに基づいて2つ質問がございます。
1. webpack.config.js のファイルはnode_modules/webpackの直下に保存するのでしょうか？
2. ファイルの保存や記述内容が正しく行われているかどうかどのように確認するのでしょうか？
以下、質問に関する補足です。1. webpack.config.jsはnode_modules/webpackの直下で保存しています。詳細はGitHubにUPしています。 https://github.com/echizenyayota/js_reciepe_v2_ch11-/commit/fa00ebb509df91a2d32edc846cc54b28bedf7758
2. 別解として教えていただいだ`$ webpack --mode=production` を`node_modules`より1つ上のディレクトリで実行すると、`-bash: webpack: command not found`と表示されます
たびたびの質問で恐れ入りますが、お手すきのときにでも教えていただければ助かります。よろしくお願い申し上げます。